# How do I solve this definite integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How do I solve this definite integral? Please show steps.

$$ \int_0^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2 \Gamma(\alpha)\beta^{\alpha}}\right) (\sqrt{x})^{\alpha} e^{-\sqrt{x}/\beta} dx $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**BIG Hint**

$$\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt=\Gamma (x).$$

Make the substitution $u=\frac{\sqrt x}{\beta }$ and see what happen.

Comment: What if $\beta\in\mathbb{C}$ \ $\mathbb{R}$?